Assigning Delegate to DataScannerViewController
I'm trying to implement a DataScannerViewController in my iOS app. I've created a delegate for it that's supposed to print when the user zooms in. The DataScannerViewController pushes as normal, but nothing prints when the user zooms in, making me believe something is wrong with my delegate.
Creating my DataScannerViewController:
func pushScanCodeViewController(){
    let dataScannerViewController = DataScannerViewController(recognizedDataTypes: [.barcode(symbologies: [.dataMatrix])],
                                                              qualityLevel: .fast,
                                                              recognizesMultipleItems: false,
                                                              isPinchToZoomEnabled: true,
                                                              isGuidanceEnabled: true,
                                                              isHighlightingEnabled: true)

    dataScannerViewController.delegate = ScanCodeDelegate(parent: dataScannerViewController)
    if DataScannerViewController.isSupported && DataScannerViewController.isAvailable {
        pushViewController(vc: dataScannerViewController)
        try? dataScannerViewController.startScanning()
    }
}

My Custom Delegate:
import UIKit
import VisionKit

class ScanCodeDelegate: DataScannerViewControllerDelegate {
    var test = "Test"
    var parent: DataScannerViewController
    
    init(parent: DataScannerViewController){
        self.parent = parent
    }

    func dataScannerDidZoom(_ dataScanner: DataScannerViewController) {
        print(test)
    }
}

I've played with the order of when I assign my delegate (after pushing the dataScannerViewController or before) and I used the debugger to see if my delegate was nil but it hasn't been. When I then zoom in, I expect it to print "Test", but nothing happens, leading me to believe there's a problem with how I set my ScanCodeDelegate class itself.
Any help would be greatly appreciated! I've checked the documentation and found guides on the DataScannerViewController but haven't found much.

There's no strong reference to the instance of ScanCodeDelegate that you create so it gets deallocated immediately.

You're my hero, what a simple solution. Thank you very much!
